# SwiftUI: How to get Today's Calendar View?

Tags: swiftui, ios14

I've been looking for a way in SwiftUI to get today's view only with hour interval's like iOS's Calendar app, if SwiftUI have default built in view for something like that then that's great, if not and there is a GitHub library to do the work then I'm okay with using that as well, I found online only a way to show a Year / Month view in SwiftUI:

```
import SwiftUI

fileprivate extension DateFormatter {
    static var month: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
        return formatter
    }

    static var monthAndYear: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
        return formatter
    }
}

fileprivate extension Calendar {
    func generateDates(
        inside interval: DateInterval,
        matching components: DateComponents
    ) -> [Date] {
        var dates: [Date] = []
        dates.append(interval.start)

        enumerateDates(
            startingAfter: interval.start,
            matching: components,
            matchingPolicy: .nextTime
        ) { date, _, stop in
            if let date = date {
                if date < interval.end {
                    dates.append(date)
                } else {
                    stop = true
                }
            }
        }

        return dates
    }
}

struct WeekView<DateView>: View where DateView: View {
    @Environment(\.calendar) var calendar

    let week: Date
    let content: (Date) -> DateView

    init(week: Date, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Date) -> DateView) {
        self.week = week
        self.content = content
    }

    private var days: [Date] {
        guard
            let weekInterval = calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, for: week)
            else { return [] }
        return calendar.generateDates(
            inside: weekInterval,
            matching: DateComponents(hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0)
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(days, id: \.self) { date in
                HStack {
                    if self.calendar.isDate(self.week, equalTo: date, toGranularity: .month) {
                        self.content(date)
                    } else {
                        self.content(date).hidden()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MonthView<DateView>: View where DateView: View {
    @Environment(\.calendar) var calendar

    let month: Date
    let showHeader: Bool
    let content: (Date) -> DateView

    init(
        month: Date,
        showHeader: Bool = true,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Date) -> DateView
    ) {
        self.month = month
        self.content = content
        self.showHeader = showHeader
    }

    private var weeks: [Date] {
        guard
            let monthInterval = calendar.dateInterval(of: .month, for: month)
            else { return [] }
        return calendar.generateDates(
            inside: monthInterval,
            matching: DateComponents(hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, weekday: calendar.firstWeekday)
        )
    }

    private var header: some View {
        let component = calendar.component(.month, from: month)
        let formatter = component == 1 ? DateFormatter.monthAndYear : .month
        return Text(formatter.string(from: month))
            .font(.title)
            .padding()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showHeader {
                header
            }

            ForEach(weeks, id: \.self) { week in
                WeekView(week: week, content: self.content)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CalendarView<DateView>: View where DateView: View {
    @Environment(\.calendar) var calendar

    let interval: DateInterval
    let content: (Date) -> DateView

    init(interval: DateInterval, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Date) -> DateView) {
        self.interval = interval
        self.content = content
    }

    private var months: [Date] {
        calendar.generateDates(
            inside: interval,
            matching: DateComponents(day: 1, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0)
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(months, id: \.self) { month in
                    MonthView(month: month, content: self.content)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RootView: View {
    @Environment(\.calendar) var calendar

    private var year: DateInterval {
        calendar.dateInterval(of: .year, for: Date())!
    }

    var body: some View {
        CalendarView(interval: year) { date in
            Text("30")
                .hidden()
                .padding(8)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .padding(.vertical, 4)
                .overlay(
                    Text(String(self.calendar.component(.day, from: date)))
                )
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to get only today's view like this one (without the days of the month at the top):

[image: iOS Calendar App]

**UPDATE:**

My progress so far to recreate the timeline view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimelineView: View {
    let hours: [String] = ["12 AM","1 AM", "2 AM", "3 AM", "4 AM", "5 AM", "6 AM", "7 AM", "8 AM", "9 AM", "10 AM", "11 AM", "12 PM", "1 PM", "2 PM", "3 PM", "5 PM", "6 PM", "7 PM", "8 PM", "9 PM", "10 PM", "11 PM"]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            HStack {
                VStack(spacing: 24) {
                    ForEach(hours, id: \.self) { hour in
                        HStack {
                            Text(hour)
                                .font(Font.custom("Avenir", size: 9))
                                .frame(width: 28, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                            VStack {
                                Divider()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 150)
        .padding(.bottom, 32)
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
        .background(backgroundPrimary)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

[image: Timeline view]

I need help re structuring the array of time that I made our strings because I'm pretty sure its not the right way, plus I would like to make it Date type as I have events coming with time stamp and would need to compare the array of time I have with the event's time to see which block it will fill

Comment: No, there's no built-in view for that

Comment: and there are many options on GitHub - search for `swiftui calendar day`

Comment: @jnpdx any idea how can I get the hours of the day as array of Date ? but in hours like this for example: ["12 AM","1 AM", "2 AM", "3 AM", "4 AM", "5 AM", "6 AM", "7 AM", "8 AM", "9 AM", "10 AM", "11 AM", "12 PM", "1 PM", "2 PM", "3 PM", "5 PM", "6 PM", "7 PM", "8 PM", "9 PM", "10 PM", "11 PM"]

Comment: That’s probably worth starting its own question — be sure to be clear about whether you’re looking for Dates or Strings. It looks like the latter in your example.

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks, check my latest update

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way that will provide you functionality you needed but i can give you a hint so that you can create this on your own using Spreadsheet -> fill your timeline in spreadsheet and then add a horizontal view that have width match to its parent's offset and height of 2 or 3, then you can add timer of 60 second that will update position of this line inside parent offset using some calculations.

Comment: Thanks, check my latest update

Comment: Good job.......